# Cursor For Volatile Table in Teradata

Tags: cursor, teradata, volatile

I have a volatile table (say, `vtTempTableForPI`) that I am creating inside a procedure. Once the volatile table gets created, I am inserting rows into it.
Once I have records in the volatile table, I need to take `MAX(ModifiedDatetime)` from this volatile table (`vtTempTableForPI`) into a local variable. However, I am unable to find a way to do so.

Here is a piece of code from my procedure for some context:

```
SELECT MAX(ModifiedDatetime)
    FROM vtTempTableForPI
    INTO lvMaxUpdateDateTime
    WHERE Template = 'Schedule_Stream'
;
```

And then I want to use this local variable to insert into another volatile table, like below:

```
SET lvQuery = '
    INSERT INTO vtScheduleVersionUpdatedTime
    SELECT
          ''Schedule_Stream''
        , ''' || CAST(lvMaxUpdateDateTime AS VARCHAR(19)) || '''
';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lvQuery;
```

I can't use this cursor on volatile table since its definition will not be present in DBC when we compile the procedure, so it will give an error. If I try to use dynamic query in order to avoid this error, I run into another error like below:

```
            SET lvMaxModifiedDateQuery = '
                SELECT MAX(ModifiedDatetime)
                FROM vtTempTableForPI
                WHERE Template = ''Schedule_Tank''
            ';

            PREPARE stMaxModifiedDateQuery03 FROM lvMaxModifiedDateQuery;
            OPEN crGetMaxModifiedDate03;
            FETCH crGetMaxModifiedDate03 INTO lvMaxUpdateDateTime;
            --CLOSE crGetMaxModifiedDate;

            SET lvQuery = '
                INSERT INTO vtScheduleVersionUpdatedTime
                SELECT
                      ''Schedule_Tank''
                    , ''' || CASt(lvMaxUpdateDateTime AS VARCHAR(19)) || '''
            ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lvQuery;
```

Below is the error that I am getting:

```
Failure occured while Creating Dynamic Query
                    SQL State:T7688,
                    SQL Code:7688,
                    SQL SESSION:  252898254,
                    Execution Start Time:2019-01-13 21:44:44,
                    Execution End Time:2019-01-13 21:44:54,
                    ERROR Message: Error occurred generating Evl code for dynamic fetch.
```

Need help!

Comment: Can you show the error message you get you try to use your 1st Select?

Comment: I am getting the following error:

`SPL1027:E(L457), Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3807):Object 'vtTempTableForPI' does not exist.'.`

While I do have a piece of code that checks if the volatile table is present prior to procedure run, it gets dropped, I don't think it matters here.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello guys, still unable to figure out a solution for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your Teradata release? This is working fine for me:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_test(
        IN v_CALC_BASIS  VARCHAR(100))

BEGIN   
   DECLARE lvMaxUpdateDateTime INT;
   DECLARE v_LogStmt VARCHAR(5000);

   SELECT Max(ModifiedDatetime)
       FROM vtTempTableForPI
       INTO lvMaxUpdateDateTime
       WHERE Template = 'Schedule_Stream'
   ;
END;

CALL SP_test ('bla');

CALL Failed.  [3807] SP_TEST:Object 'vtTempTableForPI' does not exist.
```

Either create the Volatile Table before you compile it or simply switch to a Global Temporary Table instead (recommended) .

Comment: thank you @dnoeth.
I am working with Teradata 15.10.
I think creating volatile table before compiling it would be the only viable option here.

Thanks for the help!